# Achieving Unity Render Texture from Main Camera, on Universal Render Pipeline (URP)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, urp

***Edit: I have no idea why someone devote this question, it's obviously a common issue but no solution found yet on Android, or VR devices.***

It's a Quest 2 Unity URP related issue. I am trying to save the main camera view as render texture "**SavedRenderTexture**" for later use.  It's very easy to do it in standard render pipeline via OnRenderImage().

```c#
    private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(source, SavedRenderTexture);
        Graphics.Blit(source, destination);
    }
```

I tried to achieve similar result in Unity Universal Render pipeline, below scripts are working fine in Editor Mode. But it always freezes my Quest 2 VR screen view.

```c#
    private void RenderPipelineManager_beginCameraRendering(ScriptableRenderContext context, Camera camera)
    {
        //OnPreRender();
        if (SavedRenderTexture == null)
        {
            sourceDescriptor = (UnityEngine.XR.XRSettings.enabled) ? UnityEngine.XR.XRSettings.eyeTextureDesc : new RenderTextureDescriptor(Screen.width, Screen.height, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
            SavedRenderTexture = new RenderTexture(sourceDescriptor);
        }

        MainCam.targetTexture = SavedRenderTexture;
    }

    private void RenderPipelineManager_endCameraRendering(ScriptableRenderContext context, Camera camera)
    {
        //OnPostRender();
        MainCam.targetTexture = null;
        Graphics.Blit(SavedRenderTexture, null as RenderTexture);
    }
```

I guess that the freeze screen was due to this line, maybe hardware, gpu related issue too.

```c#
        Graphics.Blit(SavedRenderTexture, null as RenderTexture);
```

In standard pipeline, we can output the source to destination by default.

However, Universal Render Pipeline is completely different structure.
I couldn't find any alternative for Universal pipeline.

I would be very appreciated for any suggestion. thanks.